# Getting multiple error on 404, 502 and 403 on nginx and slim framework

Tags: nginx, centos7

I have a nginx and slim framework setup on centos 7.

1. The first issue is config was as below.
2. Then I tried `http://myip/apiv5` and I tried `http://myip/apiv5/token` I get 502. So the error was `rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/apiv5/public/index.php"` next I change to `try_files $uri $uri/ /apiv5/public/index.php$is_args$args=404;`.
3. So now I am getting 404 but the problem is the folder do exist and the files exist accordingly. I have set the folder permission as `0755` and ownership to `nginx:nginx` and all the files in it too and also the permission for them is `0644`.
4. My question why do I keep getting 403 permission denied even though I tried changing the try_files option to e.g. just `/apiv5/public/index.php`

   http {
       log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                         '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                         '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
       server_tokens off;
       access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

   ```
   sendfile            on;
   tcp_nopush          on;
   tcp_nodelay         on;
   keepalive_timeout   65;
   types_hash_max_size 2048;
   include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
   default_type        application/octet-stream;

   # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
   # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
   # for more information.
   include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
   include /etc/nginx/blockuseragents.rules;
   limit_conn_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=addr:5m;
   server {
       listen       80 default_server;
       listen       [::]:80 default_server;
       server_name  _;
       server_tokens off;

       #root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
       root /var/www/html/;
       index index.php index.html home.html;
       # Load configuration files for the default server block.
       #include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;
       include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

   location ~ ^/apiv5 {
         try_files $uri $uri/ /apiv5/public/index.php$is_args$args;
       }

       location ~ .php$ {
        include fastcgi.conf;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
       }

       if ($request_method !~ ^(GET|HEAD|POST)$) {
           return 444;
       }
       limit_conn addr 3;
   }
   ```

Comment: please try to ask a question

Comment: @asdmin I have updated my question in number form to clarify what I have done in sequence where most options I have tried and tested yet still having issue. Currently stucked at 403 error message. I am really confused what is causing is forbidden error ?

Comment: @asdmin is it the problem with 644 permission on the files is causing this issue ? I am really lost cause I really spent many different option n effort still very clueless on why keep getting stucked here